# Re-use wifi network settings across different wifi usb dongles

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, network-manager, nmcli

I have 3 odroid wifi [module 4](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G141630348024) usb dongles (RT5572N chipset) that, for various reasons, I need to be interchangeable.

I set everything up with one, connected to a couple wifi networks and all is fine. I can pull out and put back in the dongle and it will automatically reconnect (Im using Ubuntu wily). So all good.

Interestingly if I plug in one of the others it refuses to automatically connect. I have to manually use nmcli to connect to the wifi network and from then on, auto connect works.

So it seems wifi networks are bound to the mac address of the adapter somehow.  How can I copy my setup from one dongle and make sure all the others will just work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wifi connection information is stored in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`.  You can add a new one (the syntax is clear from looking at an existing one) and restart Network Manager, and it will appear.  We can create a new one by copying an old one and changing the uuid and MAC address.

So, working as root, put the following into, say, `copyconnection.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if (( $# < 1 )); then
    exit 1
fi

# Parameter is the profile to copy
ORIG_PROFILE=$1

# Get the MAC address of wlan0
NEW_MAC=`ethtool -P wlan0 | cut -d " " -f 3 | tr [a-f] [A-F]`

# Copy the profile
SUFFIX=`mktemp -u XXXXXX`
NEW_PROFILE="${ORIG_PROFILE}.${SUFFIX}"
echo "Creating $NEW_PROFILE from $ORIG_PROFILE"
cp "$ORIG_PROFILE" "$NEW_PROFILE"

# We will need a new UUID line and a new MAC address line
NEW_UUID=`uuidgen`
NEW_UUID_LINE="uuid=$NEW_UUID"
NEW_MAC_LINE="mac-address=$NEW_MAC"

# Drop the lines in
sed -i "s/^uuid=.*$/$NEW_UUID_LINE/" "$NEW_PROFILE"
sed -i "s/^mac-address=.*$/$NEW_MAC_LINE/" "$NEW_PROFILE"
```

Make it executable

```
chmod +x copyconnection.sh
```

Then run it, with your old profile as parameter

```
./copyconnection.sh /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MyHomeWifi
```

If you want to do lots of them:

```
find /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ -type f -exec copyconnection.sh {} \;
```

Finally, restart Network Manager:

```
service network-manager restart
```

and you're done.

Full disclosure:

1. I can't test this, because I don't have an external wifi dongle to hand.  I've tested a very similar thing, adding a new profile for my only wifi adapter, and that works.
2. The use of `mktemp` is hacky.  It could, conceivably, go wrong and produce a duplicate file.  It won't, but it could.  Cleaner way would be to set its `tmpdir` to the location of the original file, but it clutters the script up so much I thought it better to just wing it :-)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Curious about the rationale though. Intuitively I would expect wifi networks to work across network cards (on the same machine)

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know the rationale for that either.